# how to make vertical scroll bar at left side and horizontal scroll bar should start from left side at bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div
        style="height: 100px; direction: rtl; overflow: auto; width: 150px;">
        <span style="direction: ltr;">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test1</td>
                    <td>Test2</td>
                    <td>Test3</td>
                    <td>Test4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test1</td>
                    <td>Test2</td>
                    <td>Test3</td>
                    <td>Test4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test1</td>
                    <td>Test2</td>
                    <td>Test3</td>
                    <td>Test4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test1</td>
                    <td>Test2</td>
                    <td>Test3</td>
                    <td>Test4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test1</td>
                    <td>Test2</td>
                    <td>Test3</td>
                    <td>Test4</td>
                </tr>
            <table>
        </span>
    <div>
</body>
</html>
```

the above code displaying vertical bar at the left side but bottom horizontal bar starting from right side. can anyone help me to get the bottom horizontal bar starts from left side?

As per above code image is coming as follows:

[image: Getting This]

I am trying to get as per below image by default:

[image: Require this]

Comment: is it not possible? i din't get it solved from any of the provided comments.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this Set the div up using this style:

```
 height: 100px; direction: rtl; overflow: auto; width: 150px;
```

And then give the span this style:

```
 <span  style="direction: ltr;">
```

This puts the vertical scroll bar on the left and set the horizontal scroll bar to the left hand side

Comment: Only negative side is, for that solution to work, the user needs Javascript turned **on**.

Comment: Thanks for providing your thoughts but it din't work for me. Still horizontal scroll bar starting from right side only.

Comment: i am doing the same what u are asking me to do but it's not working.

Comment: Sorry I thought i did it correctly but that does not work the i have been working in it for a bit and researching i don't think it is possible without creating a custom scrollbar. this was the closest i was able to get: http://jsbin.com/xupelama/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

I never even realised something like this existed.

I've edited your code (and put it in a jsbin). The thing I changed is the following:

```
<div style="height: 100px; direction: rtl; overflow: auto; width: 150px;">
    <div style="direction: ltr; width: 150px; overflow: auto;">
```

I've changed the span to a div (because that's a block element by default). The first div handles the vertical scrollbar, which should be in right-to-left mode. The second div handles the horizontal scrollbar, which needs to be default.

Here you can see a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qorozeri/1/)

Comment: Bottom scroll-bar starts to the right for me on your jsbin (using chrome if that matters).

Comment: @Sifu In what OS? My Chrome (Canary) on Mac starts on the left.

Comment: Windows XP. Chrome version 36.0.1985.125. Same on Aurora (Firefox) and IE8.

Comment: You are right. That does indeed happen on windows. Weird, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: This is weird that even cross platforms there are differences in fromatting.. HTML/CSS formatting is just such a pain sometimes..

Answer (score 0):

remove `direction: rtl;` and it will solve your problem

Comment: If i remove direction: rtl; vertical scroll bar will come on right side which i don't want.